# How to protect the trigger from deletion?

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

Version: PostgresQL 9.6

I create a trigger.

Even if I create a trigger as a superuser, the owner of the database can remove the trigger.

Is it possible to protect the trigger from deletion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot keep the owner of the table from dropping a trigger on it unless you want to go to the extreme of writing an event trigger for that.

Maybe you should use a different permission concept where you give people only limited privileges if you want to keep them from dropping your triggers. Instead of allowing others to own tables, grant others privileges on the tables.